# Can't find source of GitHub Pages website

Tags: github, github-pages

I noticed a typo on `http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/` . Judging by its URL it seems to be a GitHub Pages website, so I thought I would fix the typo via a GitHub pull request.

If I am not mistaken, the HTML for a `http://xyz.github.io` website is at `https://github.com/xyz/xyz.github.com` so I went to https://github.com/dblock/dblock.github.com .

Surprise: The HTML does not look to be the same at all. There is not even a `dotnetinstaller` folder.

What kind of magic is operating here?

Are my assumptions about how [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles) work false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct link is https://github.com/dblock/dotnetinstaller/tree/gh-pages

Your assumption is not false but work only for User or Organisation page not for project page, so github.com/dblock/dblock.github.com is for dblock.github.io and dotnetinstaller (if it's not a folder of a User or Organisation page) is located at github.com/dblock/dotnetinstaller in the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: Unfortunately that repository does not seem to contain the string `dotNetInstaller is a widely used, general-purpose setup bootstrapper for Microsoft Windows 95, 98, 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 2008 and Windows 7.` which is visible on the left on the website...

Comment: Yes it is but code for project GitHub Pages is under "gh-pages" branch not "master". To switch between branchs click on button "branch: master" near a green button...

Answer (score 1):

Also, it is quite possible to have a GitHub page active (and public) for a private repository.